# Log file for upgrades

Tags: upgrade, mysql, log, 19.10

Is there a logfile for the upgrade process of Ubuntu available? My upgrade from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 failed for MySQL but I did not manage to see what went wrong in the terminal window. Therefore I want to browse a possible log file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's at `/var/log/dist-upgrade`